# Traduction de « Toy Block »

Tags: traduction, anglais, jeux, art

Je cherche à traduire l'anglais « *toy block* » en français. J'utiliserais spontanément le terme LEGO, mais je ne veux éviter tout nom de marque, il me faut un terme générique. « Jeu de construction de briques » ne me paraît pas naturel, et je cherche à désigner les briques, pas le jeu.

Le contexte est la description d'[œuvres de l'artiste Masafumi Tanaka](http://www.tanaka-masafumi.com/ceramicart/frame01.htm).

---

I'm struggling to find the translation of "Toy block" in French. I am French myself and we usually use the brand "LEGO" to describe this type of game. However, I need a more generic word and "Jeu de construction de briques" does not sound natural. Moreover, I need to refer to the block itself, not the game.

The context is a description of [works by artist Masafumi Tanaka](http://www.tanaka-masafumi.com/ceramicart/frame01.htm).

Comment: Note qu'en anglais, les Lego, ce sont plutôt des *bricks* que des *blocks*. *Block* évoque un jouet moins élaboré avec des pièces qui ne s'imbriquent pas. P.S. pas besoin de parler anglais ici, il y a plus de francophones qui parlent le français que l'anglais !

Comment: Ah bon, va pour le français alors. _Toy block_ est le nom de la série artistique donc pas possible de le convertir en _brique_. En y réfléchissant bien, je pense que je n'ai même pas besoin de traduire le nom de la série, vu que l'expression n'est pas complexe et que l'idée est compréhensible juste en regardant l'oeuvre.

Comment: Tu pourrais peut-être ajouter ce que tu as déjà traduit du passage qui t'intéresse (et l'original), le contexte peut aider à suggérer de meilleures alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*English reader version :*

I'd use **briques ludiques**.

And when the context is clear enough, just **briques** should be the best choice.

---

*Version française :*

Je proposerais **briques ludiques**.

Et quand le contexte le permet sans introduire d'ambiguité, on pourra opter pour **briques** tout simplement.

Comment: Merci. En fait, le contexte n'est pas clairement défini. Je dois écrire une description pour les oeuvres figurant ici: http://www.tanaka-masafumi.com/ceramicart/frame01.htm . J'aime assez le "ludique" dans "brique ludique" carcela renvoie bien l'idée que l'artiste veut faire passer.

Comment: @JulienBourdon Dans ce contexte artistique, j'aime bien *brique ludique*. Mais hors contexte, je suis d'accord avec [Un francophone](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/3061), ça risque de ne pas être compris.

Answer (score 3):

J'utiliserai *Lego* ou *briques de type Lego*. J'avoue que face au *brique ludique* proposé dans une autre réponse, je ne saurais pas de quoi il s'agit.

Comment: C'est pour une description officielle et Lego est une marque déposée. Merci quand même pour la réponse!

Comment: @JulienBourdon Pour être neutre : *brique de jeu de construction*.

Comment: Gilles, tu aurais pu en faire une réponse, c'est exactement ce que j'allais proposer et qui me semble une bien meilleure réponse que "briques ludiques" qui ressemble aux tentatives désespérées de francisations stupides (surtout qu'on est aussi tenté par la pseudo-contrepèterie "biques lubriques").

Comment: @Gilles Totalement d'accord avec Un francophone, ça mériterait une réponse en tant que tel, car c'est bien mieux que *briques ludiques*

Comment: @Gilles *briques de jeu de construction* ?! On perd la concision et la forme est lourde et inélégante avec son double *de*.

Comment: @gemp Tentatives « désespérées » ? « francisation stupide » ? Pourquoi ces provocations qui n'apportent rien au débat, à part éventuellement un peu d'animosité : était-ce le but de ton intervention ? Et enfin : penses-tu réellement (!) que ma proposition est mauvaise parce que tu as trouvé une (très approximative) contrepèterie ?

Comment: Oups, désolé, je ne voulais pas paraître agressif ! Me relisant, je re-constate qu'il faudrait que je m'abstienne de commenter fatigué, surtout quand j'essaye de faire de malheureuses tentatives humoristiques. En plus, j'aime bien "briques ludiques" même si je trouve ça peu approprié ici. Vraiment désolé, je ferai plus attention.

Answer (score 2):

I would use *une brique*, nothing fancier. If we assume the context is known, there should be no ambiguity, and you would be perfectly safe using just that word.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using the word to describe artwork so the context is not known. I think I'll use "briques ludiques" as suggested by Romain above.

Answer (score 2):

J'aurais tendance à utiliser *blocs de construction* plutôt que *briques*, d'autant que l'artiste utilise différentes formes de pièces (qui sont d'ailleurs assez eloignées de pièces LEGO authentiques).

Answer (score 0):

"Jeu de construction" tout seul peut suffire.

Comment: Mais la question contient la précision explicite : *Je cherche à désigner les briques, pas le jeu.*